# Add new id column and fill incremental value to already existing table

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to add an id column to my table which is having around 500cr rows and update it with  incremental value. Please suggest what is the best way of doing it. 
I tried running a query to update the value and store in new table but the query failed after 6 hrs saying timeout. Please help.

Comment: The best way is not to so at all because in most cases this is just intermediate field that you can derive on fly in your queries depends on your  logic. If you can explain your use case we might be able to help you. in any case  - I would recommend you to edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We need this to act as identity column. So once we are able to update the incremental value in the new column, then going forward we would be pushing almost a million rows everyday including the incremental value for this column. Also, we would be processing a column of everyrow into multiple rows in seperate tables and this new column will act as a foreign key to the other tables.

Comment: Google BigQuery is not regular relational database where you need to follow normalization rules. In BigQuery you better keep your data de-normalized. No primary no foreign keys of transaction nature! Whole transaction in one row.

Comment: I know and understand but this is a request from our client and we have do it somehow.

Comment: you mentioned you tried something and it failed - was it ROW_NUMBER() based? show what you tried so we can help

Comment: Yes exactly.. so in select query i selected all column and row_number() over() to export all data along with row number to a new table so that i can delete the old table and again copy this new table to name it to original table but the query failed after 6hrs saying timed out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`row_number() over()` is quite expensive!
You should try `row_number() over(partition by some_field)` to redistribute numbering across partitions.
Here, you should pick partition field which has reasonable number of distinct values in your table - let's say 1K or so.
After this "first round" - you will have compound key: `partition_field` + `incremental number` that you can use as a primary/foreign key or if you want you can then combine further those two into one key

Comment: If i do this then going forward everyday i need to run this update query. Also we don't have any partition in our table. Also, according to requirement we need to have only incremental value as identity column and not compound. We cannot change the requirements. May be i can suggest this to them and see if they agree else i need to find a way to somehow do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: have in mind - first "phase" with compound key is to address expensiveness of row_number() over(). if this will get through w/o issue - in next step - you can combine this into one key - this can be relatively simple another query! but as you mentioned in your question  - this is just one time action - going forward you will have to take care of "generating" this number on your application side  - bigquery do not have functionality of auto numbering, etc.

Comment: I know big query don't have this functionality thats why i will be taking care of it before loading the new file to big query. My loading file will contain the next incremental values.

Comment: Sure. And please do check my post tomorrow as it is night time at my location so can't do anything now, will try out something tomorrow and update in comments. Also i am very new to big query, so trying to explore every possible solutions.

Comment: i am on SO each and every day (as many of us are). If you will have more/new question(s) please post them here on SO as a new question versus keeping it as a forum in this post. SO is not a forum but rather question/answer type of site where many professionals like me more than happy to help you

Comment: Sure. Thanks. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work better when you need to generate numeric ids:

```
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY GENERATE_UUID())
```